# How to malloc properly when dealing with 2-D pointers and what are some of the advantanges of using a 2-D pointer array?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am currently, working on solving a maze and so far I have read the maze from a text file and stored it into an 1-D pointer, however, I am trying to store it into a 2-D pointer array, but I keep getting a segmentation fault. Also, my second question, what are some advantages of using a 2-D pointer array? I do not seem to understand how to properly implement them. This is my first time using 2-D pointers so I'm not as a great at it, however I would like to improve so I can become good at it in the future. Thank you so much for the help in advance :)

Here is what I have done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mazegen.h"
#define  BUFFERSIZE 500

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    char*readFile;
    char**storeMaze;
    FILE*fp;
    int i;
    i=0;
    readFile = malloc(sizeof(char)*(BUFFERSIZE)+1);

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error opening file, incorrect format. <programNam <inputfileName>\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Empty File. Error. Exiting Program.\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        while(fgets(readFile,sizeof(readFile),fp) != NULL)
        {
            storeMaze = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(strlen(readFile)+1));
            strcpy(storeMaze[i], readFile);
        }
    }

   free(readFile);
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your `printf` is wrong. You're missing a quote.

Comment: first `sizeof(inputFile)` --> `101`

Comment: sorry about that, I accidently forgot to put the quotation when I was typing my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've dynamically allocated space for the `fgets()` to read into, but you then pass the wrong size as the size.  There's no reason to use `malloc()` unless you're on an unusually small machine (say less than 8 MiB — yes, I mean megabytes — of main memory).

```
char readLine[4096];

while (fgets(readLine, sizeof(readLine), inputFile) != NULL)
```

Or, if you insist on `malloc()`, specify 101 as the size in the call to `fgets()`.

You're compiling  on a 32-bit system so `sizeof(inputFile) == sizeof(FILE *)` which is 4 on your system.  Hence you got up to three characters and a null from the input for each call to `fgets()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  static allocation seems to be working well.